# How to change MySQL root password via a file?

Tags: mysql

How do I change the MySQL root password in ubuntu server via a file?
The file may be any shell script or normal text file.

***My try:***

Normally the below command, in the terminal, changes the password for newly installed mysql.

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'newpass'
```

But while doing it via file it's showing the bellow error.

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

So can someone help me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop the MySQL Server: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
2. Start the mysqld configuration: sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables
3. Login to MySQL as root: mysql -u root mysql
4. Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password:

   ```
   UPDATE
     mysql.user
   SET
     Password = PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD')
   WHERE
     User = 'root';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   exit;
   ```

**Note:** This method is not regarded as the most secure way of resetting the password, however, it works.

Comment: Is these operations are possible via a file? if yes, can you please show an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have never assigned a root password for MySQL, the server does not require a password at all for connecting as root follow :
[Resetting Permissions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)